# insights/analytics for linked in api?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I have been using the linkedin API for a while now but haven't really developed with it more than authorizing users and share items in their news stream

having looked at the API here-

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-API

its hard to say whether or not you could get stats or insights from the API for an application- rather than a user?

Am I missing something in the docs in my application I would rather pull info from the API and present stats to the administrator of my application

(i'm using php and oauth)

Answer (score 0):

Other than the Statistics API that you link to, that allows you to pull stats about the member's own network, there is no way to retrieve application stats via the API. You would need to set-up some kind of local monitoring of calls made to the API via your application if you wanted to track stats for the application.

Comment: i have done this but was expecting a slimmed down version of facebook insights